# Angularjs $resource dynamic headers with $save

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I am trying to add dynamic headers to a $resource like so:

```
angular.module('app')
 .factory('API', function ($resource, API_URL) {
  return {
   event: function(userId){
    return $resource(API_URL + '/event/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    }, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'service': 'API',
          'userId': userId
        }
      },
      save: {
        url: API_URL + '/event/:id/accept',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'service': 'API',
          'userId': userId
        }
      }
    })
  }
 };
});
```

Using this allows me to pass in headers which works fine when using the get.

When I want to save a object this just returns undefined:

```
var event = new Muse.event('jonro')(object);
```

Could someone please help explain why I cant use $resource in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'save' uses POST verb usually ([$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource))

How do you call the save method?
From the reference:

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
>   [success], [error])

What does the Developer Tools says if you look your requests?

Comment: event.$save({id: $stateParams.id});

Comment: This is how I call save on a new model object, this works without the dynamic headers

Comment: Just saw your comments, as you already wrote in a reply you missed the object to save :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using this method for updates:

```
API.event('jonro').save({id: $stateParams.id}, object)
```